# (Office.js) ItemSend Event not firing when doing a Mail Merge from Microsoft Word

Tags: outlook, ms-word, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have configured an Outlook Add In using Office.js that hooks in to the ItemSend event in order to modify an email body prior to sending the email. The add in was configured (yesterday) using the `office-generator`

```
npm install -g yo generator-office
yo office
```

I modified this slightly to add a function that handles the `ItemSend` event

```
<Hosts>
  <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
    <DesktopFormFactor>
      <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
        <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />
      </ExtensionPoint>
      ...
```

The add in is functioning as expected on the Outlook Web version and on Outlook Desktop, When I send an email from the outlook desktop app, I can see that my code is running as expected.

The issue i'm running into is that I need this code to run when a Mail Merge is performed from Microsoft word, however, when I do this, my code is not being executed. Is it possible to execute a custom javascript function to modify the email body, when mail is sent from a Mail Merge in Microsoft word?

Interestingly, Hubspot's add in apparently runs successfully when sending mail this way (Mail Merge from Microsoft Word), and they are able to modify the email body (re-write links and add tracking pixel) for each email that gets sent out. So it should be possible, but I'm not sure what integration point is needed, or how they are achieving it.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Outlook web addins (as you have done with office-generator) do not run in Word. I am not familiar with hubspot, but it might be a COM addin. Could you tell us more about the scenario? example, is it to re-write links/insert content?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Hey! Yes, basically we are sending mail merges from microsoft word to many sales contacts, we have found this to work really well because we get the formatting we want, and we the delivery is very good vs. other platforms. (i.e. doesn't go to spam). We would like to insert a pixel into these emails so that we can check open rates, and re-write the links such that we can determine who is clicking on our links. The `ItemSend` event is able to do the job fine when sending email from outlook, but not when sending using the Word mail merge. Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, this functionality is not possible at this time. You may be able to accomplish something similar via a Taskpane add-in entirely in Outlook. However, you wouldn't only be able to send one email. You may be able to use EWS or REST to call server functions to send multiple emails...but this is pretty far from the extensive features that Word Mail Merge Provides.